# display the html in the email body

Tags: php, jquery, imap

I am working on my code to send the email and store the email in the sent folder. I have got a problem with display the html in the output because it will display the html tags just like this:

```
Hey Ron!<div><br></div><div>How are you?</div><div><br></div><div>I hope you are well.</div><div><br></div><div>Speak soon,</div><div>Chris</div>
```

It should be:

```
Hey Ron!

How are you?

I hope you are well.

Speak soon,
Chris
```

I have tried this:

```
strip_tags($message)
htmlentities($message)
htmlspecialchars($message)
```

I'm getting this in the output using each of these code from above:

strip_tags:

```
Hey Ron,I am doing well thank you.&nbsp;Yes I am interested to meet you this weekend.See ya there then.Chris
```

htmlentities

```
&lt;p style=&quot;color: rgb(70, 70, 70); font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;Hey Ron,&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;color: rgb(70, 70, 70); font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;I am doing well thank you.&amp;nbsp;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Yes I am interested to meet you this weekend.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;See ya there then.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Chris&lt;/p&gt;
```

htmlspecialchars

```
&lt;p style=&quot;color: rgb(70, 70, 70); font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;Hey Ron,&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;color: rgb(70, 70, 70); font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;I am doing well thank you.&amp;nbsp;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Yes I am interested to meet you this weekend.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;See ya there then.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Chris&lt;/p&gt;
```

Here is the full code:

```
<span id="avater_email" class="avater_email">chris@domain.com</span>
<span id="avater_name" class="avater_email">chris</span>
<span id="emailsubject"><b>Hey  </b></span>
<span id="send_to" email="chris@domain.com" data-email-address="chris@domain.com">chris<chris@domain.com></chris@domain.com></span>

<div id="quickreply" class="reply-message" hidefocus="false" aria-label="Message Body" g_editable="true" role="textbox" aria-hidden="true" aria-multiline="true" contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" style="direction: ltr;min-height: 135px;width: 840px; padding-left: 25px; font-size: 13px;" itacorner="6,7:1,1,0,0">Hey Ron!<div><br></div><div>How are you?</div><div><br></div><div>I hope you are well.</div><div><br></div><div>Speak soon,</div><div>Chris</div></div>

var username = 'myusername';
var password = 'mypassword';
var mailserver = '{imap.domain.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}';

$(document).on('click','#send_button', function(e) {
    var name = $("#send_to").text();
    var email = $("#send_to").attr('data-email-address');
    var from_name = $("#avater_name").text();
    var from_email = $('#avater_email').text();
    var emailbody = $("#quickreply").html();
    var subject = $("#emailsubject").text();

    if($("#replymessage").css("display") == "block")
    {
        subject = 'Re: ' + $("#emailsubject").text();
    }


    $.ajax({
        url: 'sendMail.php',
        type: 'POST',

        data : {
            username: username,
            password: password,
            mailserver: mailserver,
            to_name: name,
            send_to: email,
            from: from_name,
            from_email: from_email,
            emailsubject: subject,
            emailbody: emailbody
        },

        success: function(result)
        {
            alert(result);
            //$(this).attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});


sendMail.php:

<?php

require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "Mail/mime.php";


if (isset($_POST['send_to']))
{
    $toArrs = explode(",", $_POST['send_to']);
    $toArr = array_unique($toArrs);

    foreach($toArr as $to) 
    {
        $from = $_POST['from_email'];
        $to = $_POST['send_to'];
        $subject = $_POST['emailsubject'];
        $message = $_POST['emailbody'];
        $host = "smtp.domain.com";
        $port = "587";
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $mailserver = $_POST['mailserver'];
        //$mailserver = $mailserver .'.Sent';

        $headers = array ('From' => $from, 
            'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject,
            'Reply-To' => $from,
            'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
            'Content-Type'  => 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
            'Received' => 'from smtp.domain.com',
            'Date'  => date("r"),
            'Message-ID' => sprintf("<%s.%s@%s>",
                base_convert(microtime(), 10, 36),
                base_convert(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8)), 16, 36),
                'domain.com'));

        $params = array ('host' => $host,
            'port' => $port,
            'auth' => 'PLAIN', // Note 1
            'socket_options' => array('ssl' => array('verify_peer_name' => false, 'verify_peer' => false)), // Note 2
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password);

        $mime_params = array(
            'text_encoding' => '7bit',
            'text_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
            'html_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
            'head_charset'  => 'UTF-8'
        );

        $crlf = "\r\n";
        $mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));
        $body = $message;
        $mime->setTXTBody($body);
        $mime->setHTMLBody($body);
        $body = $mime->get($mime_params);
        $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

        $smtp = Mail::factory ('smtp', $params);
        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);


        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) 
        {
            echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo("<p>Email has been sent!</p>");

            $mailbox = imap_open($mailserver, $username, $password);
            imap_append($mailbox, $mailserver.'.Sent',
                "From: ".$from."r\n".
                "To: ".$to."\r\n".
                "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n".
                "Date: ".date("r", strtotime("now"))."\r\n".
                "\r\n".
                $body.
                "\r\n"
                );

            // close mail connection.
            imap_close($mailbox);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

What I want to achieve is when I send the email and store the email in the sent folder, I want to display the hml in the output when I open my email without displaying the html tags.

Can you please show me an example how I could display the html in the output when I open my email without display the tags?

Thank you.

**EDIT: Here is the update code:**

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once('Mail/IMAPv2.php');
require_once "Mail/mime.php";

if (isset($_POST['send_to']))
{
    $from = "Chris <chris@domain.com>";
    $to = $_POST['send_to'];
    $subject = $_POST['emailsubject'];
    $message = $_POST['emailbody'];
    $smtp_hostname = "smtp.domain.com";
    $port = "587";
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $mailserver = $_POST['mailserver'];

    $headers = array ('From' => $from, 
        'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject,
        'Reply-To' => $from,
        'Content-Type'  => 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
        'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
        'Received' => 'from smtp.domain.com',
        'Date'  => date("r"),
        'Message-ID' => sprintf("<%s.%s@%s>",
            base_convert(microtime(), 10, 36),
            base_convert(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8)), 16, 36),
            'domain.com'));

    $params = array ('host' => $smtp_hostname,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => 'PLAIN', // Note 1
        'socket_options' => array('ssl' => array('verify_peer_name' => false, 'verify_peer' => false)), // Note 2
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password);

    $mime_params = array(
        'text_encoding' => '7bit',
        'text_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
        'html_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
        'head_charset'  => 'UTF-8'
    );

    $crlf = "\r\n";
    $mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));
    $body = $message;

    $mime->setTXTBody($body);
    $mime->setHTMLBody($body);
    $body = $mime->get($mime_params);
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);
    $smtp = Mail::factory ('smtp', $params);
    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);


    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) 
    {
        echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo("<p>Email has been sent!</p>");

        $mailbox = imap_open($mailserver, $username, $password);
        imap_append($mailbox, $mailserver.'.Sent',
            "From: ".$from."r\n".
            "To: ".$to."\r\n".
            "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n".
            "Date: ".date("r", strtotime("now"))."\r\n".
            "\r\n".
            $message.
            "\r\n"
        );

        // close mail connection.
        imap_close($mailbox);
    }
}
?>
```

**I have tried this:**

```
imap_append($mailbox, $mailserver.'.Sent',
    "From: ".$from."r\n".
    "To: ".$to."\r\n".
    "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n".
    "Date: ".date("r", strtotime("now"))."\r\n".
    "\r\n".
    $body.
    "\r\n"
);
```

**And I have also tried this:**

imap_append($mailbox, $mailserver.'.Sent',
        "From: ".$from."r\n".
        "To: ".$to."\r\n".
        "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n".
        "Date: ".date("r", strtotime("now"))."\r\n".
        "\r\n".
        $mail.
        "\r\n"
    );

Comment: `Content-Type'  => 'Content-Type: text/plain;` your telling the mail client its text, not html

Comment: @tim what do I need to change from this `'Content-Type'  => 'Content-Type: text/plain;`?

Comment: Don't throw arbitrary escaping functions at strings, such as applying htmlentities/specialchars twice.

Answer (score 1):

There is no function in PHP to do what you asked for.

You need to create own PHP function. First replace `<br>` for new line (I've replace for 2 new lines, as in your example), then remove the other HTML tags.

```
function br2nl($str) {
    return preg_replace("~<br[ /]*>~", "\r\n\r\n", $str);
}

$str = br2nl('Hey Ron!<div><br></div><div>How are you?</div><div><br></div><div>I hope you are well.</div><div><br></div><div>Speak soon,</div><div>Chris</div>');
$str = strip_tags($str);

echo '<pre>';
echo $str;
echo '</pre>';


---- result
Hey Ron!

How are you?

I hope you are well.

Speak soon,Chris
```

**Full code sendMail.php**

```
<?php

require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "Mail/mime.php";

function br2nl($str) {
    return preg_replace("~<br[ /]*>~", "\r\n\r\n", $str);
}

if (isset($_POST['send_to']))
{
    $toArrs = explode(",", $_POST['send_to']);
    $toArr = array_unique($toArrs);

    foreach($toArr as $to) 
    {
        $from = $_POST['from_email'];
        $to = $_POST['send_to'];
        $subject = $_POST['emailsubject'];
        $message = $_POST['emailbody'];
        $host = "smtp.domain.com";
        $port = "587";
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $mailserver = $_POST['mailserver'];
        //$mailserver = $mailserver .'.Sent';

        $headers = array ('From' => $from, 
            'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject,
            'Reply-To' => $from,
            'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
            'Content-Type'  => 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
            'Received' => 'from smtp.domain.com',
            'Date'  => date("r"),
            'Message-ID' => sprintf("<%s.%s@%s>",
                base_convert(microtime(), 10, 36),
                base_convert(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8)), 16, 36),
                'domain.com'));

        $params = array ('host' => $host,
            'port' => $port,
            'auth' => 'PLAIN', // Note 1
            'socket_options' => array('ssl' => array('verify_peer_name' => false, 'verify_peer' => false)), // Note 2
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password);

        $mime_params = array(
            'text_encoding' => '7bit',
            'text_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
            'html_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
            'head_charset'  => 'UTF-8'
        );

        $crlf = "\r\n";
        $mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));

        $body = br2nl($message);
        $body = strip_tags($body);
//      ^^^^^^^^ edited noHTML message 
        $mime->setTXTBody($body);
        $mime->setHTMLBody($body);
        $body = $mime->get($mime_params);
        $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

        $smtp = Mail::factory ('smtp', $params);
        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);


        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) 
        {
            echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo("<p>Email has been sent!</p>");

            $mailbox = imap_open($mailserver, $username, $password);
            imap_append($mailbox, $mailserver.'.Sent',
                "From: ".$from."r\n".
                "To: ".$to."\r\n".
                "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n".
                "Date: ".date("r", strtotime("now"))."\r\n".
                "\r\n".
                $message.
//              ^^^^^^^^ original HTML message
                "\r\n"
                );

            // close mail connection.
            imap_close($mailbox);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. When I use `<b>How are you?</b>`, it will not show the bold in the email when I sent it. Any idea?

Comment: @chrisoojer: sure, you wanted to remove HTML tags. Or not? It's why there is (and you tried too) `strip_tags()`.

Comment: yes I do want to remove HTML tags, but when I send the email and open my email, I want to display the html tags. How I could do that?

Comment: @chrisoojer: when you remove HTML tags (edit source message), you can't show them again. How to email client has to know if you want/don't want to show them?

Comment: @chrisoojer: maybe, if possible, try on line 108 send updated message (br2nl, strip_tags?) and on line 130 put into sent folder original message with HTML. I see no more possibilities here.

Comment: in which code do I need to try on line 108 that i could use message(br2nl, strip_tags) and line 130 that i put into sent folder? if you can show me an example that would be great

Comment: @chrisoojer: in your `full code` from question, of course. What else code it should be? But I don't know if it's possible, you have to try it.

Comment: @chrisoojer: I've updated my answer. Can't test it, try if it's working...

Comment: I have tried the code you have updated but it didn't work, however I've modifed the code and sent the email i can read my email in html but I have found there is a problem somewhere in `imap_append` that did not store the html. Can you help?

Comment: @chrisoojer: sorry, can't help you more. imap_append in unknown for me, just tried how it could be when I saw your code.